# How pass the variable from bean shell sample to other request

Tags: jmeter

```java
import java.util.Random;        
Random r = new Random();
int low = 1;
int high = 4;
int randomvalue = r.nextInt(high-low) + low;
log.info("-------------------------");
String Value="10000"+randomvalue+"A";
log.info(Value);
```

How to pass the data present in the `Value` variable to other requests in JMeter?

Answer (score 0):

Change Beanshell to [JSR223 Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) and add value to JMeter variable

```
 vars.put("Value", Value);
```

You can call it later as `${Value}` or inside `JSR223 Sampler` as `vars.get("Value")`

Or save using JMeter's property (effect all threads)

```
 props.put("Value", Value);
```

You can call it later as `${__P(Value)}` or inside `JSR223 Sampler` as `props.get("Value")`

Comment: Thanks , it worked. Any reason why we should not use bean shell directly

Comment: @user1153899 you can but it's not advised by JMeter team, and can be deprecated

Answer (score 0):

1. It is recommended to use JMeter built-in test elements where possible, your requirement can be implemented via [__Random()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__Random) and [__intSum()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__intSum) functions combination. Both provide possibility to store the generated value into a JMeter Variable. Check out [Apache JMeter Functions - An Introduction](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-functions-introduction) article to learn more about JMeter Functions concept.
2. If you absolutely have to go for scripting be aware of `vars` shorthand for [JMeterVariables](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html) class instance, it provides read/write access to JMeter Variables so you can put the generated value into i.e. `${foo}` JMeter variable as:

   ```
   vars.put("foo", Value);
   ```
3. [Since JMeter 3.1 it's recommended to use JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language for scripting](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) so consider migrating to Groovy on next available opportunity.